# could not find implicit value for parameter FromRequestUnmarshaller Akka

Tags: scala, akka, slick

I am trying to create this api for objects like user, location, and visits. And I want to have post methods for adding and updating values of these objects. However, I do not know how to pass the object to the route of an api. A part of my route for the location update:

```
trait ApiRoute extends MyDatabases with FailFastCirceSupport {
     val routes =
          pathPrefix("locations") {
            pathSingleSlash {
              pathPrefix(LongNumber) { id =>
                  post { entity(as[Location]){
                    location => {
                      onSuccess(locationRepository.update(location)) {
                        result => complete(result.asJson)
                      }
                    }
                  }
}
```

However, when I try to build update in such a way I get an error:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter um: akka.http.scaladsl.unmarshalling.FromRequestUnmarshaller[models.Location]
[error]               post { entity(as[Location]){
```

Json encoder for the location:

```
package object application {
      implicit val locationEncoder = new Encoder[Location] {
        final def apply(location: Location): Json = Json.obj(
          ("id", Json.fromLong(location.id)),
          ("place", Json.fromString(location.place)),
          ("country", Json.fromString(location.country)),
          ("city", Json.fromString(location.city)),
          ("distance", Json.fromLong(location.distance))
        )
      }
```

I am using Slick to model and get all the data from the database:

```
case class Location (id: Long, place: String, country: String, city: String, distance: Long)

class LocationTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Location](tag, "locations") {
  val id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
  val place = column[String]("place")
  val country = column[String]("country")
  val city = column[String]("city")
  val distance = column[Long]("distance")

  def * = (id, place, country, city, distance) <> (Location.apply _ tupled, Location.unapply)
}

object LocationTable {
  val table = TableQuery[LocationTable]
}

class LocationRepository(db: Database) {
  val locationTableQuery = TableQuery[LocationTable]

  def create(location: Location): Future[Location] =
    db.run(locationTableQuery returning locationTableQuery += location)

  def update(location: Location): Future[Int] =
    db.run(locationTableQuery.filter(_.id === location.id).update(location))
}
```

So what should I add or change in my code to get rid of the exception and make it work?

Answer (score 3):

If you are adding or updating a Location, that Location needs a Decoder as well to read the serialized data from the client that comes across the wire as the HTTP entity.  Akka HTTP also needs a FromRequestUnmarshaller in conjunction with the Decoder to decode the request entity which in this example is the Location you want to add or update, and the one that you extract the id from.

Using [Scala's Circe library](https://github.com/circe/circe) for JSON handling, then the [Akka HTTP JSON project has part of what you need](https://github.com/hseeberger/akka-http-json).  As that project indicates, add the following to your build.sbt

```
// All releases including intermediate ones are published here,
// final ones are also published to Maven Central.
resolvers += Resolver.bintrayRepo("hseeberger", "maven")

libraryDependencies ++= List(
  "de.heikoseeberger" %% "akka-http-circe" % "1.18.0"
)
```

and then you can mix in the support you need using FailFastCirceSupport or ErrorAccumulatingCirceSupport.  Add that to the class that defines your routes with

```
class SomeClassWithRoutes extends ErrorAccumulatingCirceSupport
```

or

```
class SomeClassWithRoutes extends FailFastCirceSupport
```

depending on whether you want to fail on the first error, if any, or accumulate them.

You still need to have a Decoder[Location] in scope as well.  For that you can [see Circe's documentation](https://circe.github.io/circe/codec.html), but one quick way to define that if you want the default field names is to use the following imports in your route definition class or file so that Circe creates the necessary Decoder for you.

```
import io.circe.generic.auto._
import io.circe.Decoder
```

Comment: I am already using circe. I have updated the first code part in my question. However, I still get this error

Comment: How about when you use the circe imports as shown in my update?

Comment: The update helped me. Thanks! However, I get ``The request's Content-Type is not supported. Expected:application/json`` error when I check it in Postman. Although, it may not be connected with circe decoding

Comment: That indeed sounds unrelated. What `Content-Type` did you use for the Postman request?